# How do I setup services to start when Gitlab is ready?

Tags: 14.04, server, upstart, git

I have a few Upstart services that I would like to have started once Gitlab is started and *ready to serve repositorie*s.

There is a `gitlab-runsvdir` Upstart service (came with the `gitlab` package) that starts Gitlab on bootup, however using

```
start on started gitlab-runsvdir
```

did not prove to help, as Gitlab was still not ready when that service was started.

**How can I setup Upstart services to start when Gitlab is ready to serve repositories?**

---

Contents of `/etc/init/gitlab-runsvdir.conf`, as requested:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown
respawn
post-stop script
   # To avoid stomping on runsv's owned by a different runsvdir
   # process, kill any runsv process that has been orphaned, and is
   # now owned by init (process 1).
   pkill -HUP -P 1 runsv$
end script
exec /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start
```

As far as I know, this came with the `gitlab` package.

---

Comment: Could you post the content of gitlab-runsvdir?

Comment: @CameronNemo Done.

Comment: I use gitlab as well, and the hard part is determining when gitlab is fully ready. It's not fully ready until all the unicorn workers are (until then you'll get 500/502 errors on the web interface). In practice that seems to take about a minute for me. You can examine your logs after a `gitlab-ctl restart` to see when the unicorn processes are up for you.

Comment: Maybe having a post-start script in the upstart job that tries to ping the web interface for a couple minutes, then times out if it is not up by then, would be ideal?

Comment: @muru: how about changing the upstart runlevel and priority of the services that depend on `gitlab`?  (I don't use gitlab...)
Talk to me in the chat room about this.

Answer (score 1):

Try gitlab-ctl. 
You can find it into the following paths :

```
/usr/bin/gitlab-ctl 
/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-ctl
```

for example

```
exec /usr/bin/gitlab-ctl start
exec /usr/bin/gitlab-ctl stop
```

Comment: This will start or stop gitlab, but I want to start services only once gitlab is actually ready to accept requests